# How to set timeout apoc.load.json in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher, connection-timeout, neo4j-apoc

I run a Cypher query `CALL apoc.load.json("URL")` and Neo4j returns this error message:

> Can't read url ... as json: Read timed out

How to set timeout for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a configuration to put into your `neo4j.conf` file :

```
apoc.http.timeout.connect=10000
```

Value is in millisecond.
You can take a look at the code for more information : https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/blob/b9a4e587265e4f168098e2d1e6135ff19985fc59/src/main/java/apoc/util/Util.java#L234

NB: There is also a `apoc.http.timeout.read` params.

Cheers

Comment: De nada ! And have fun with Neo :)